# Java Game random id in an array

Tags: java

Hello I have a game where you walk around looking for clues as to what happened.
I have a map.txt with numbers on it representing each block. if the number is equal to 5 a table is created. I want to have clues on the table. I want to find out how many tables are created in the map and assign each table an id but none of the ids can be the same and the id number cant be bigger than the amount of tables for that map. Here is my code so far:

table class

```
public class TableWithClue {

    public int x, y;
    public boolean search = false;
    public Rectangle r, r1;

    public int time = 0;
    public int timer = 100;
    public int aftertime = 0;
    public int aftertimer = 100;

    public boolean foundsomething = false;
    public TableWithClue(int x, int y,int id) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        r = new Rectangle(x - play.camx, y - play.camy, 20, 30);

    }

    public void tick() {
        r = new Rectangle(x - play.camx, y - play.camy, 20, 30);

        if (r.intersects(play.p.r)) {
                if(Keys.isPressed(Keys.e)){
                search = true;
                Sound.snap.play();


            }
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        Image img;

        if (search) {
            ImageIcon i62 = new ImageIcon("res/tiles/table1.png");
            img = i62.getImage();
            g.drawImage(img, x - play.camx, y - play.camy, null);

        } else {
            ImageIcon i62 = new ImageIcon("res/tiles/table1.png");
            img = i62.getImage();
            g.drawImage(img, x - play.camx, y - play.camy, null);

            if(r.intersects(play.p.r)){
            ImageIcon i162 = new ImageIcon("res/gui/openstuff.png");
            img = i162.getImage();
            g.drawImage(img, Comp.size.width /2 - 95, 50, null);

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.BOLD,15 ));
            g.drawString(" E to search ", Comp.size.width /2 - 32, 88);
            }
        }

        if(search && r.intersects(play.p.r)){
            if(time >=timer ){
                if(aftertime >= aftertimer){
                search = false;
                time= 0;
                aftertime = 0;
                }else{
                    aftertime++;
                }
            }else {
                time++;
            }



            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect((int) play.p.x - 55, (int) play.p.y - 70, 120, 40);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect((int) play.p.x - 55, (int) play.p.y - 70, 120, 40);

            if(time <timer && time != 0){
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.BOLD,15 ));
            g.drawString("Searching",(int) play.p.x - 30, (int) play.p.y - 55);
            }
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect((int) play.p.x - 35, (int) play.p.y - 50, (80 * time) / timer, 10);
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            g.drawRect((int) play.p.x - 35, (int) play.p.y - 50, 80, 10);

            if(aftertime<=aftertimer && time >= timer){
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.BOLD,12 ));
                g.drawString("Found Nothing",(int) play.p.x - 34, (int) play.p.y - 55);

            }
        }else{
            search = false;
        }


        if(play.debug){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        }else{

        }

    }
}
```

The tables are created here in a different class called block:

```
 public void interactables() {
    if (id == 5) {
        screens.interactables.t1.add(new TableWithClue(x ,y));

    }
 }
```

Here is the map class:

```
public class map {

    private String path;
    private int width, height;

    private static block[][] blocks;

    private boolean open = false;;

    public Image i2;

    public map(String path) {

        this.path = path;

        loadMap();

    }

    public void loadMap() {
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            width = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            height = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            blocks = new block[height][width];

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

                String line = br.readLine();

                String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");

                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    blocks[y][x] = new block(x * block.blocksize, y * block.blocksize, Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]));
                }
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < blocks[0].length; j++) {
                if (blocks[i][j].x + 50 > play.camx && blocks[i][j].x - 50 < play.camx + Comp.size.width + 10 && blocks[i][j].y + 50 > play.camy && blocks[i][j].y - 50 < play.camy + Comp.size.height + 10) {

                blocks[i][j].render(g);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static block[][] getBlocks() {
        return blocks;

    }

    public void interact() {

        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < blocks[0].length; j++) {

                    blocks[i][j].interactables();

            }
        }

    }

    public void addNPC() {

        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < blocks[0].length; j++) {

                    blocks[i][j].NPC();

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Can you make your question more specific if possible? You've posted a requirement but as yet have not told us exactly what code has you stuck or how your current code is not working.

Comment: That's the thing.. I have no idea how I could tackle this problem so I have no code that has me stuck I just don't know how to do it

Comment: Note that it is standard to capitalize class names (to separate them from field/variable names). So it would be `Block` instead of `block` (This isn't mandatory, but helps with organization and code readability)

Comment: What about iterating through your blocks-array (as I assume you store your map with this) increasing a counter each time you find a table entry (5). Then you can directly assign this counter as unique ID to your table. Anything else you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will want to store the table's ID in the `TableWithClue` class. Then, you will want a static int in your `block` class. This variable will store the next table ID; each time, the next ID is passed to the table's constructor, then the variable is incremented. So the first table loaded would be table 0, the second would be table 1, etc.